# GraphQL .NET DocumentExecuter returns too much information

Tags: .net, graphql

I'm using DocumentExecuter to perform a graphql query and mutation in .NET. I have no error, but the response is way to big compare to what I asked.

below is the query and a sample of the response :
[image]

I don't understand why I receive all this informations and how can I retrieve only what I have asked for.

Here is my code :

```
    public class GraphQLController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly IDocumentExecuter executer;
    private readonly ISchema schema;
    private readonly IServiceProvider serviceProvider;

    public GraphQLController(IDocumentExecuter executer, ISchema schema, IServiceProvider sp)
    {
        this.executer = executer;
        this.schema = schema;
        this.serviceProvider = sp;
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<ActionResult<object>> PostAsync([FromBody]GraphQLQuery query)
    {
        var inputs = query.Variables;
        var queryToExecute = query.Query;

        var result = await executer.ExecuteAsync(o => {
            o.Schema = schema;
            o.RequestServices = serviceProvider;
            o.EnableMetrics = false;
            o.Query = queryToExecute;
            o.OperationName = query.OperationName;
            o.Variables = (inputs != null ) ? new Inputs(inputs.ToDictionary()) : null;
            
        }).ConfigureAwait(false);
        return this.Ok(result);
    }
}
```

If I don't use a controller as I'm doing here, everything work as expected.But I want to understand why I have this behavior if I'm doing this way